# Count total cells to the left of given critiria

Tags: excel, count, formula

I'm struggling to find a work around to this.

Below I have some data. I'm trying to add a formula in Q cells that looks up the value in R, then uses that value to count how many cells are the left of it in the table to the left. Seems a weird thing to do, but I want to use the final result in another formula that fetches a predetermined title.

So in R2 I have 00:37:22. I need the formula to count from the left in the table how many cells (regardless if they are empty or have data) are there until M2 when it finds the matching value. The results should be 13.

I've made a example below of what I've got and what I'm after.

I'm unsure if excel can even do this, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: How it is 13, 3, 6? What is logic?

Comment: Your result is just the column number of the item, not the columns to the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Match() formula to get the column number of cell that contains matched value.

=MATCH(R9,A9:O9,0)

the formula is (matching value, range, 0 for exact match)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Match function to return the amount of columns

```
 =MATCH(R5;A5:N5;0)
```

[image]